# /etc/ssh/sshrc does not work for SFTP

Tags: ssh, sftp

I need the server to execute command automatically when user successfully connected to SFTP. For that purpose in SSH there is a `/etc/ssh/sshrc` file, but unfortunately it does not work on SFTP connections.

So is there this same file, but meant for SFTP?

---

> Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver).

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu..? May be necessary.

Comment: version 18.04.2

Comment: Maybe the `patch` could have handled something that can cause this issue. I suggest you try version 18.04.4 then... And let's see if it now works.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work fine with `/etc/ssh/sshrc` file. It was my fault, because I had a script execution in this file, and that script did not have necessary permissions. Setting permissions to execute by other users solved the issue.